# Hand shields bluetooth antenna in Google Pixel 4a 5G?

Tags: google-pixel-4a

Is it a reported issue with the Google Pixel 4a 5G, that the bluetooth connection of the device is disturbed when having it in your hand?

My headphones work flawless if the pixel sits on my desk, but stuttering begins when it is in my hand..

I wonder whether the issue is specific to my device.

Comment: Of course your body can weaken a radio signal, especially when your hands come close to the antenna. I would recommend to check tear-down videos of your device to learn where the antenna is located and make some tests if holding the device in different ways have an effect on your problem.

Comment: It shouldn't though. Bluetooth and wifi operating frequency is 2.4GHz. They easily pass through walls.

Comment: I know, this is why I was surprised myself @defalt. And indeed the issue was not with the hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having troubles with your new Google Pixel 4a 5G from late 2020 in 2021 or later I recommend downloading the latest Google connectivity apps and update your system to  the latest Android version.

I was forced to set-up my device offline, the original version must have had some kind of bug with the bluetooth. After installing the updates everything worked.

I was able to determine, that the issue is software related after conducting a few tests. It turns out, that not holding the phone but turning on its screen is causing the stuttering.